# Why is Blender deforming my texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I clearly need someone's help on this problem ! I did a texture map on substance painter and got a pretty good result.

[image: Substance Render]

I pluged all the maps on a blender material and the texture is anormally displayed.

[image: Ambiant Occlusion annormally displayed on Blender]

[image: Black spots]

I figured out it's the base color map who does this but i doin't know how to fix this. I tried on Marmoset and everything was good.

[image: Marmoset View]

So why Blending is deforming my texture map ?

Comment: i don't understand what problem you are describing. can you maybe encircle the areas you are referring to that are "abnormally displayed" ?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I edited with a new image to highlight the anormal spots !

Comment: is it possible to share the file? https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly the result of triangulation, Blender triangulates the model in other way, which leads to this result. To deal this it, try following:

1. Select this face, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Select edge, that's created by triangulate operation, then press <kbd>E</kbd> ⇾ Rotate Edge CW

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much !